# replaceWith jquery not works

Tags: jquery, replacewith

```
var gethtml  = $("#topmenu > li.l89 a").text().split(' ')[1].replaceWith('Any World');
```

The text is not changing even after using `replaceWith` as shown above.

Comment: Replacewith is a method of a jQuery object, not of the string returned by .text()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you call .text() you are no longer working with a jQuery object, but with a plain string.
You can do it like this...

```
var text = $("#topmenu > li.l89 a").text()
  , textParts = text.split(' ');

textParts[1] = "Any world";
console.log('New text', textParts.join(" "));
```

I wrote the long version for you to see the steps. If you want you can do it on a single line, but it is not very readable anymore.

Comment: yes but how i can now change $("#topmenu > li.l89 a") first word with textParts[1] ?

Comment: something like this should do it `$("#topmenu > li.l89 a").text(textParts.join(' ')​);​`

Comment: thanks i will choose other road like this : 
>>>>>>>>>>
var first = $("#topmenu > li.l89 a").text().split(' ')[1];
var second = $("#topmenu > li.l89 a").text().split(' ')[2];

$("#topmenu > li.l89 a").html("<span style='font-size:10px;' padding->"+first+"</span> "+second);
>>>>>>
but your post is very good thanks :)